# I tried to fetch data from firestore in my react project. I used getDoc method

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
        const getUserData = async () => {
            const userRef = doc(db, "Users", userEmail);
            const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
            if (docSnap.exists) {
                setUserDetails(docSnap.data);
            }
        };
        getUserData();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}, []);
```

snapshot.ts:302 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_document')

Everything is correct I checked many times but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Where does `userEmail` come from? Have you checked the value is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to exec exists [`docSnap.exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot.md#documentsnapshotexists).